# Close auto-suggestion popup in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to do this? You might say "just keep typing", but sometimes it'll happen when I want to start a new line(like in XML files when I'm defining various attributes, each on their own line). So if I hit Enter, it inserts the first suggestion and I have to ctrl+z it and hit Enter again. Clicking elsewhere in the editor window kills the suggestion popup, but that involves taking my hand off the keyboard, and then I have to re-insert the cursor in the right place.

Frankly I think auto-suggestion is annoying, but I can't seem to turn it off in XML files. Unchecking the "automatically make suggestions" box in XML->XML Files->Editor does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I don't get you wrong I think you are looking for the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Comment: Also, if you're within a bracket or some other text you can hit the ▶ right arrow key.

Answer (score 1):

You can Disable Auto Complete using

ellipse -> window -> preferences -> java -> Just Click on Content Assist(dont expand) ->

uncheck AutoActivation

thats it Click apply and OK

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned...

Window -> Preferences -> XML -> XML Files -> Editor -> Content Assist ->

...and uncheck *Automatically make suggestions* should do the trick. There is also the Typing section under Editor that has a place to make changes but the above should stop the IDE from making suggestions.

Comment: Like I just said, unchecking that box does nothing.